# Android Activity Indicator

Tags: android, activity-indicator

I am programming for an Android application. while clicking a button, it calls a service to display the necessary contents. For calling the service and to parse the XML data present in that service it takes nearly 5 to 10 seconds. In these 5 seconds time period I need to display an activity Indicator with a text stating that "Loading. Please wait...". This part works fine for iPhone. But not in Android.

Any help would be appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Did you try implementing ProgressDialog for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). Look at "Creating a ProgressDialog" section. Try to parse the XMLs in AsyncTask. When you start the task just show the progress dialog. When the task finishes -  hide the progress dialog.

Comment: I think he is using titanium for development.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show a message when your service is running you can use Progress Dialog for that.

```
 ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Your message..");
                dialog.show();
```

to dismiss this progress dialog use

```
 dialog.dismiss();
```