# android loading message

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Download a file with Android, and showing the progress in a ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog)
>   [Android Activity Indicator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025652/android-activity-indicator)

i am really a novice in android 
I am doing an app connected with a webservice(xml) and it works good, but my app load the screen with the views incomplete and then shows the data.
Iwould like to implement a " gettin ready" dialog when all the data has been downloaded and showed from the server.

Thanks for your help

Comment: use AsyncTask for showing progress bar and first downloading data from server then so it without freezing UI and rendering of incomplete views

Comment: See these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5025652/android-activity-indicator, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085227/android-show-progress-indicator-of-parse-while-downloading-a-xml and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302479/android-activity-indicator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog= ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this, "", 
                "Loading. Please wait...", true);

progressDialog.dismiss(); // for close the dialog bar.
```

Comment: great man..
do you know how to keep a progressDialog for 2 seconds?

Comment: @funkeeiads Let the thread sleep for 2000 ms